# Como mostrar uma imagem a cada 5 segundos javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom a minha dúvida é a seguinte, gostaria de saber, como faria para que o javascript desse um intervalo de 5 segundos antes de editar de imagem.

Meu código:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    if(2>1){
        document.getElementById("imagem").src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+1&w=350&h=150";
        document.getElementById("imagem2").src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+2&w=350&h=150";
        document.getElementById("imagem3").src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+3&w=350&h=150";
    }
}
```

```html
 
<img id="imagem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+1&w=350&h=150">
<img id="imagem2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+2&w=350&h=150">
<img id="imagem3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+3&w=350&h=150">
```

http://pastebin.com/Bc82kPDt

Ou seja que houvesse um intervalo em cada src de 5 segundos.

Que primeiro o javascript editasse o id "imagem", passado 5 segundos editasse o id "imagem2" etc...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar isso manipulando os objetos do DOM, removendo a imagem anterior e criando uma nova no lugar.

#### Javascript

```js
var i = 1;
var id = 'imagem'
// Intervalo em milissegundos (1s == 1000ms)
var milissegundos = 2000; // 5000 = 5 Segundos

// Executa a função a cada intervalo de tempo
var interval = setInterval(function(){

  // Recebe o elemento
  var img = document.getElementById(id);

  i++;
  
  // Seta o source da nova imagem
  img.setAttribute('src', 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+'+i+'&w=350&h=150');

  
}, milissegundos);
```

```html
<div id="img-area">
    <img id="imagem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+1&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
```

---

#### jQuery

```js
var i = 1;
var id = '#imagem'
// Intervalo em milissegundos (1s == 1000ms)
var milissegundos = 2000;

// Executa a função a cada intervalo de tempo
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  i++;
  // Seta o source da nova imagem
    $(id).fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(id).attr('src', 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+'+i+'&w=350&h=150').delay(100).fadeIn(200);
    });

}, milissegundos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-area">
    <img id="imagem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Imagem+1&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
```

#### [Exemplo de Roleta](https://jsfiddle.net/nt72qk2z/1/)

Comment: Peço desculpa, mas eu sou bocado novato na área do javascript, diga-m e uma coisa, Se eu quiser adicionar mais imagens a editar id's diferentes como faço?

Comment: Opa @Gonçalo, quais são os dados que você tem? Você tem um array com as imagens? Quantas imagens queres adicionar por vez?

Comment: Bom vou tentar explicar direitinho, funciona da seguinte forma: Eu tenho um img de amarelo claro, um img de verde claro, um img, de laranja claro, um img roxo claro e um img vermelho claro, ai tipo se a condição cor for igual a vermelho, quero simular que passa por todas as cores até chegar vermelho ou seja é uma roleta, que basicamente  mostra a imagem do verde escuro > mostra a imagem do verde claro, espera 1 segundo,  ativa  mostra imagem do laranja escuro > mostra imagem do laranja claro etc... até chegar ao vermelho

Comment: Hmm. Entendi @Gonçalo  Você precisa fazer isso com Javascript puro ou pode usar alguma biblioteca como [jQuery](https://jquery.com)?

Comment: Posso usar Jquery, nao tem problema.

Comment: @Gonçalo, adicionei um link na resposta. ;)

Comment: Amigo diga-me so uma coisa, isto funciona no mesmo id de img?

Comment: Sim @Gonçalo, você pode fazer direto `document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('src', 'caminho/da/imagem.jpg');`

Comment: Já consegui Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `setTimeout` para gerar o delay desejado.

```
function iniciarSlideImagens() {

    var exibirImagens = function(current) {
        var arrImgsAmarelas = [ 'amarelo0.png', 'amarelo1.png' ];
        var arrImgsLaranjas = [ 'laranja0.png', 'laranja1.png' ];

        document.getElementById("imagem").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsAmarelas[current];
        document.getElementById("imagem1").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsLaranjas[current];

        if (++current >= arrImgsAmarelas.length) {
            current = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(function() { exibirImagens(current); }, 5000);
    };

    exibirImagens(0);

}

iniciarSlideImagens();
```

Comment: Boa Tarde, isso no caso altera apenas um id de um img, eu queria que alterasse varios ids de varios imgs.

Comment: @Gonçalo Editei a resposta.

Comment: Eu coloquei o código da seguinte forma: http://pastebin.com/TLLAT0JE E só me aparece apenas a imagem da img.

Comment: Como assim a imagem da img? Faltou você alterar o seletor para a imagem laranja, que deveria ser `imagem1` e você manteve `imagem2`.

Comment: Bom Dia, peço desculpa mas sou mesmo iniciante na área, pode-me indicar o que é seletor?. Obrigado.

Comment: O problema era na linha `document.getElementById("imagem2")` que deveria ser `imagem1`. Editei o código da resposta para fechar com o seu exemplo.

Comment: Amigo, o que está a acontecer é isto:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYC0TPUldPc Eu queria que primeira ligasse o amarelo(amarelo1.png) passada 5 segundos desligava o amarelo(amarelo0.png) e ligasse sem intervalo de tempo o laranja(laranja1.png) e etc...

Comment: Opa @Gonçalo, depois de ver o que você quer, essa solução do Oeslei te cabe bem, fiz uns ajustes nela. https://jsfiddle.net/nxvh7fru/